# Java, GridBagLayout. How add components right to other component

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

i'm learning JSwing and i discovered the GridBagLayout.

I'm trying to create a simple calculator, i did it with adding multiple JPanel setting each preferedSize but when i resize the window frame the panels won't resize too.
Then i found out the GridBagLayout.

But this i what i get: [Wrong calculator with GridBagLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYnN7.png)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Calc extends JFrame {

private final int  WIDTH = 300;
private final int  HEIGHT = 450;

public Calc(){

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());




    mainPanel.add(createButtons(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    add(mainPanel);


}

private  JPanel createButtons(){

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();

    panel.setLayout(layout);


    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();

    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){

        panel.add(new JButton(""+i), g);
        g.gridx++;
        if(g.gridx == 3) {
            g.gridx = 0;
            g.gridy++;
        }

    }


    return panel;



}


public static void main(String... args){

    Calc calc = new Calc();
    calc.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

it should be something like this:
[Right calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m44vI.png)

i tried:

- to set an anchor... but it doesn't work,
- to create multiple JPanel(one with GridLayout) but doesn't work

if you don't want to spoon code, it's okay.. but from where should i start?

**Edit:**
I figure out how to arrange the buttons... but i can't set the header to fill all the x-axis:
Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

JPanel top;
JPanel left;
JPanel right;


private class CButton extends JButton{

    private Operation operation;

    public CButton(){

    }



}

public ButtonPanel(){

    initComponent();
    initLayout();
}

private void initLayout() {

    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    this.setLayout(layout);

    layout.columnWeights = new double[] {3,1};
    layout.rowWeights = new double[] {1, 1};

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    c.weightx = 5;
    this.add(top, c);
    c.gridy++;
    c.weighty=1;
    this.add(left, c);
    c.gridx++;
    this.add(right, c);




}

private void initComponent() {

    top = new JPanel();

    top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        top.add(new JButton("bbb"));
    }



    left = new JPanel();

    left.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){

        left.add(new JButton(""+i));

    }

    right = new JPanel();
    right.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        JButton btn = new JButton("aa");
        right.add(btn);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(new ButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setSize(300, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

It should be: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDCi3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do everything within a single panel, having some buttons that span over multiple columns.

So I give you a different example to layout buttons using a single GridBagLayout, here you can define your button arrangement as an array of values, check if it could be a good starting point for your project.

```
package test;

import static test.Calculator.Buttons.*;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Calculator extends JPanel {
    //Here define all possible buttons with labels
    public enum Buttons {
        PERCENT("%"), CE("CE"), CLEAR("C"),
        ONE("1"), TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4"), FIVE("5"), SIX("6"), SEVEN("7"), EIGHT("8"), NINE("9"), ZERO("0"),
        ADD("+"), SUB("-"), MULT("x"), DIV("/"), RESULT("="), DECPOINT(".");
        
        protected String text;
        
        Buttons(String txt) {
            this.text=txt;
        }
        
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
    };
    
    //This array contains your keypad layout, contiguous repeated elements will span across multiple columns (e.g. ZERO). 
    protected Buttons[][] keyPad = {
        {PERCENT, CE, CLEAR, DIV},
        {SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, MULT},
        {FOUR, FIVE, SIX, ADD},
        {ONE, TWO, THREE, SUB},
        {ZERO, ZERO, DECPOINT, RESULT}
    };
    
    Map<JButton, Buttons> sourceMap=new HashMap<>();
    
    ActionListener padListener=new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            onKeyPadPressed(sourceMap.get(e.getSource()));
        }
    };
    
    public Calculator() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c=new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx=1.0;
        c.weighty=1.0;
        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        
        for (int y=0;y<keyPad.length;y++) {
            for (int x=0;x<keyPad[y].length;) {
                Buttons b=keyPad[y][x];
                if (b==null) {
                    continue;
                }
                JButton btn=new JButton(b.getText());
                c.gridx=x;
                c.gridy=y;

                c.gridwidth=0;
                while(x<keyPad[y].length&&keyPad[y][x]==b) {
                    c.gridwidth++;
                    x++;
                }
                add(btn,c);
                
                sourceMap.put(btn,b);
                btn.addActionListener(padListener);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //Callback method, whenever a button is clicked you get the associated enum value here
    protected void onKeyPadPressed(Buttons b) {
        System.out.println("Pressed "+b);
        switch (b) {
//          case ZERO:
//          .... here your logic
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new Calculator());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code above produces this result, but it's really easy to add/remove buttons and change the layout.

[image]

Comment: But in a more abstract way...
Can you give me some advices or "a starter kit of things to know" with GridBagLayout?
And i have some questions about the layout manager.

Like:
1) should i make the main container's layout manager a gridbaglayout, in this way i can set weights.
2) Weights are like a fraction of the entire space, right?

Comment: @andre The official Java tutorial is quite detailed: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html; with this layout you work with a grid where each component can also span across multiple columns/rows (`gridwidth, gridheight` attributes). The base width/height of a column/row is determined by the component's preferred size, but with a calculated use of weightx/weighty you can distribute the extra space (if the containing panel is bigger than the required size of the components) between the columns/rows proportionally.

Comment: @andre Another point to understand is that these attributes define the size of the "cell" where the component is located, but to position the component within the cell you can use the anchor and/or the fill attributes (in my example fill is BOTH, so no need to anchor, since the component will fill all the available space)

Comment: Okay, tysm, i will see the official tutorial, ty again!